# python-mysql-connector throws error while executing command

Tags: python, mysql

I'm rewriting my codebase and converting all f-strings to C-like string formatting (%s), but this error is there every time:

```py
>>> import mysql.connector as mc
>>> conn = mc.connect(username = "root", password = "root")
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("use %s", ("test",))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\whode\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 569, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\whode\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 599, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\whode\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 487, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''test'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database names should not be quoted.  Just do

```
cursor.execute( "use test;" )
```

Alternatively, specify the database name in the `connect` call.

Comment: so if I use f-strings for databases, would that be alright?

Comment: I also get the same error while using table names

Comment: Yes, you do not want database names, table names, or field names to be quoted.  Just field values.